# Variable Life Cycle on MVC page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, variables, lifecycle

Quick but dumb question.  That kind of cascades a little bit.  If I create a variable on an aspx page, will it be available to an ascx that my aspx partially renders.  Also, How does the aspx page handle those variables?  I know for a fact, those variables last a lot longer than say a TempData or ViewData variable.  Here is a small example of what I am wondering about...

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h3><% Response.Write(((ViewData["MESSAGE"] == null) ? "Edit Encounter Information" : ViewData["MESSAGE"] ));            
       int encounter = int.Parse((string)TempData["ENCOUNTID"]);
       int PopPatId = int.Parse((string)TempData["POPPATID"]);
       int PatID = int.Parse((string)TempData["PATID"]);
       int population = (int)TempData["POPULATIONID"];
       string templates1 = (string)TempData["TEMPLATES"];
       string MRN = ((TempData["MRN"] == null) ? "Add Patient":(string)TempData["MRN"]);
       ViewData["TEMPLATES"] = templates1;         
    %>        
    </h3>   
    <div id="countdownDiv" style="display:none">
    <p><font color="#990000"><b>Sorry, This Data has expired. Please Refresh The page.</b></font></p>    
    <%
        Html.BeginForm("EditTemplate", "PatientACO", new { Template = PatID, popID = population, PopulationPatID = PopPatId, Enc = encounter });
        TempData["TEMPLATES"] = templates1;
        %><input type="submit" value="Refresh" id="test" /><%
        Html.EndForm();%>     
</div>   
<% Html.RenderPartial("_EditTemplate"); %>
<%: Html.ActionLink("Back", "TemplateInfo", new { PopulationID = population, ActiveAll = "1" })%>
```

Note I have created variables.  How long will they last?  can I use those variables now in the ascx page that I call below?

Comment: That's the worst code I've seen today. You should really move all logic to either your controller or the view model (depending on what the logic does)

Comment: A lot of that code is used to manipulate how the view looks.  I guess I could pass all of that down to the controller, but I would still need to pass up the results to the view somehow.  I figured it would be easier to understand if that logic was on the view that would be used.  Isn't a view model more M-V-VM ish?

Comment: The `Model\ ` folder is for view models. View models should be used to remove logic from the view. `((TempData["MRN"] == null) ? "Add Patient":(string)TempData["MRN"])` belongs in a property called `MrnText` in the view model.

Comment: I am using Asp.Net MVC Version 2... I only have a Models folder... I don't know if that is in a later version, but That is good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those variables can only be used within the scope of the aspx page.  Any page rendered via `RenderPartial` or `RenderAction` will need to define their own set of variables to use.  If you need to share data among the aspx page and the ascx page then you need to pass a model or `ViewData` to your `RenderPartial` view and access the data that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass models to partial views <%: Partial("PartialViewName", Model)%>